# Line integrals giving different values depending on what it is integrated against?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

For example, take a look at the solution to 4:

[image]

Considering the interval is always the same (from x=1 to x=8), how can it give different values depending on what you integrate against?

Comment: It is fundamental that it gives values dependent on the differential.  They are, in fact, different quantities altogether.  A simpler example: Let's say that I have a velocity vs time profile.  if I integrate velocity with respect to time, I get distance.  if, however, I integrate velocity with respect to velocity, I get kinetic energy per unit mass.

Comment: @RonGordon: If we assume velocity is on the y-axis and time is on x-axis, if you integrate velocity with respect to velocity, what you're essentially doing is computing the area shaded in blue, right? http://i.imgur.com/sFE2wU2.png

Comment: Ummm...I don;t think so.  A $v$ vs $v$ plot is a straight line of slope $1$, so you get $\frac12 v^2$ for the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest to explain it starting with $ds$: Given a curve, $C$, and point function $G(x,y)$, $ds$ is a differential distance or "line element" along the curve, as I'm sure you're aware, whereas $dx$ and $dy$ are *projections* of that line element onto the $x$ and $y$ axis, respectively. In vector form, if $d\vec{s}$ is the *tangent vector at the points $(x,y)$*, then $dx=d\vec{s}\cdot \vec{i}, dy=d\vec{s}\cdot \vec{j}$. You are basically only adding up one component of the motion in the $dx,dy$ cases.

Applying this to the point function $G(x,y)$, you are projecting the derivative $\frac{d}{ds}G(x,y)$ onto the x and y axes: $\frac{dG_C}{dx}|_{(x,y)} = [\frac{dG}{ds}\frac{ds}{dx}]_{(x,y)}$